Parametrize project root in emacs project
While using project in Emacs I need to specify a large set of include directories
for flycheck syntax checker.
I use C++ on Linux and I mention the include/ dirs in .dir-locals.el.
The format used is something like:
((c++-mode . ((flycheck-checker . c/c++-gcc)
     (flycheck-gcc-include-path . (
        "/my/project/root1/include1"
        "/my/project/root1/include2"
        "/my/project/root1/include3"
        "/my/project/root1/include4"
        "/my/project/root1/include5"
        "/my/project/root1/include6"
))
    
    (flycheck-gcc-definitions . ("<Some Macro >")
              )
     )))

The problem with above approach is if I have several copies of the source code (meaning different project root areas) for doing different tasks I need to write the above for each such copy which requires management each time some include/ directory is added/deleted.
Is there a way to parametrize /my/project/root in some variable & define the variable once only instead of repeating in each include/ directory?
That way each project root copies will have 1 such defn of the variable which will point to the current root & the rest would be identical. (I can then maintain a single copy of 99% of the .dir-local.el file & all source areas will use the copy & override the variable for project root on their own.)
Maybe there is a simple way of doing this, but as I am new to emacs I can't find it.

This?  First (setq myroot1 "/my/project/root1/"), then either of  (concat myroot1 "include1")  or  (expand-file-name "include1" myroot1).

Like you, I'm also new to emacs, but I believe you can define a custom variable in your .dir-locals.el file to hold the project root path. Here's an example:
((nil . ((my-project-root . "/my/project/root1"))))

You can then use this variable to define your flycheck-gcc-include-path like so:
((c++-mode
  . ((flycheck-checker . c/c++-gcc)
     (flycheck-gcc-include-path
      . ((lambda ()
           (mapcar (lambda (dir) (concat my-project-root dir))
                   '("/include1" "/include2" "/include3" "/include4" "/include5" "/include6")))))
     (flycheck-gcc-definitions . ("<Some Macro>")))))

For other root projects, simply change the path like this:
((nil . ((my-project-root . "/my/project/root2"))))

Remember, documentation is your best friend! Here's a helpful link where you can learn more about directory-local variables and related solutions: Emacs Lisp Reference Manual on Directory Local Variables.

Thanks for the answer! While it certainly looks to be in the right direction , however, it isn't working. As I am no expert in LISP as well it took me some time to make it work.

It appears that the Cdr part is not evaluated properly here for .dir-locals.el.  For you & others who may face this issue, here is what I did (capturing only the relevant change): (eval . (setq flycheck-gcc-include-path
(cl-concatenate 'list (mapcar (lambda (dir) (concat my-project-root dir)) my-project-include-dirs) my-project-external-include-dirs)). Here, I give provision for any external lib includes as well. Rest is similar.

Thank you for the feedback. Really appreciated.
